# Django Rest Framework approach for JSON API standards

Tags: python, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm quite new to Django Rest Framework. I couldn't find on the docs something that would allow me to serialize my models according to the JSON API standards ([jsonapi.org](http://jsonapi.org/)).

Let's suppose I have the following models.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Car(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    brand =  
    model = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    plate = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I would like to serialize it in a way that it would provide me with the following output:

```
{
    "data":[
        {
            "type": "Person",
            "id": 1,
            "attributes": {
                "name": "John",
            },
            "relationships": {
                "cars": [
                    {
                        "data": {
                            "type": "Car",
                            "id": 1,
                            "attributes": {
                                "brand": "Bugatti",
                                "model": "Veyron",
                                "plate": "PAD-305",
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        "data": {
                            "type": "Car",
                            "id": 2,
                            "attributes": {
                                "brand": "Bugatti",
                                "model": "Chiron",
                                "plate": "MAD-054",
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        },

        {
            "type": "Person",
            "id": 2,
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Charllot",
            },
            "relationships": {
                "cars": [
                    {
                        "data": {
                            "type": "Car",
                            "id": 3,
                            "attributes": {
                                "brand": "Volkswagen",
                                "model": "Passat CC",
                                "plate": "OIJ-210",
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        "data": {
                            "type": "Car",
                            "id": 4,
                            "attributes": {
                                "brand": "Audi",
                                "model": "A6",
                                "plate": "NAD-004",
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        }
    ],

    "meta":{
        "backend_runtime": "300ms", // processed at the view
    }
}
```

Comment: im pretty sure you will have to convert the model manually to that form

Comment: I think that would violate the ORM principles. I shouldn't have to design my models to represent it in a specific JSON structure. I wonder what are the DRF tools for represent it in a flexible way.

Comment: I guess this https://github.com/django-json-api ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your serializer to return the data any way you want. For example, if you want to ignore the exact model structure you can do the following

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class PersonSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """
    Person/Car serializer
    """
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField()
    attributes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_attributes(self, obj):
        return {"name": obj.name}
```

If you want a serializer structure that is closer to your models, you can relate model serializers using the following approach:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializes car object"""    
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('id', 'brand',)


class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializes person and car relationship"""
    car = CarSerializer(read_only=True) 

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'car',)
```

In both cases, you would be passing a queryset to the serializer that contains these fields (and in the nested model serializer, the existing relationships).

Answer (score 1):

Parsers and Renderers are the component that allows you to alter the serializer's response.
Note that there's already a third party that implements jsonapi with Django REST framework: https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api

Dont forget to look at the [Django REST framework third party page](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/third-party-packages/) if you're looking for something.